# Adonis js pagination with dynamic query building

Tags: adonis.js

I am building a query like this

```
    let searchData = request.all()

    let products =  Product.query().where('product_type', searchData.type).with('singleImage').paginate(1, 20)

    if(parseInt(searchData.minPrice) > 0 && parseInt(searchData.maxPrice) > 0) {
        products.where("lowerPrice", ">=", searchData.minPrice).where("upperPrice", "<=", searchData.maxPrice)
    }

    // more conditions and query goes here
```

It doesn't work because of `.paginate(1, 20)` and if I remove pagination it works.

Comment: any solution you got??

Comment: Yes got it.. Paginate and fetch is kind of same thing. so we have to use 
await products.paginate(page, 1) at the end. paginate will work as fetch.

Comment: Great thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute paginate or fetch after put all your conditions. For example:

```
let searchData = request.all()

let products = Product.query()
          .where('product_type',searchData.type)
          .with('singleImage')
// Remove pagination from here

if(parseInt(searchData.minPrice) > 0 && parseInt(searchData.maxPrice) > 0) 
{
 products.where("lowerPrice", ">=", searchData.minPrice)
         .where("upperPrice", "<=", searchData.maxPrice)
}

// Put all your conditions 


// Finally execute paginate with await or yield it depends of adonis version (await or yield)

products = await products.paginate(1,20)
```